# GIT - Group all the changes made in different branches

Tags: git, branch, atlassian-sourcetree, cherry-pick

sometimes the developers push the work related to a single ticket into different branches, the name of the branch always contain the ticket code (example: "Ticket-002_added_objects" (where "Ticket-002" is the code of the ticket). In sourceTree: if I search for "Ticket-002", it returns all the commits containing changes for the specific ticket. What I currently do to see all the changes is: create a new branch and cherry-pick the commits one-by-one (starting from the bottom).
Is there a smarter way to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me the smarter solution is to set policies where your developers don't want to do arbitrary things that create extra work.  Maybe make them take turns collecting the commits for a release

Comment: I agree with Mark - the smarter way is to put all changes related to a ticket into a single branch, and to reject PRs that contain changes related to more than one ticket. *(You do require PR reviews, right?)*

Comment: I completely agree with you guys and I already communicated it to the devs as a rule. The devs should push the changes related to a ticket to a single branch even across different releases (for example in case of a bugfix): they should rebase the original branch on top of the last changes first. But how can I prevent this? It is indeed something happening before the creation of a PR